# 2 wifi dongle , 1 for weak internet connection 1 for hotspot

Tags: hotspot

I am having ınternet connection from my neighbour. 
But it is very weak. I want to connection with my  desktop's 1 wifi dongle and share internet to 2nde wifi dongle.
 The i want to share with 2nde wifi dongle as a  hotbot.

Is there and way to do this in win7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, you can use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/). Easy to use and very intuitive.